# Have a running clock on terminal during python script execution

Tags: python, console

I'd like to, while my program is running, have a clock running in the console. Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: of coarse its possible ... it might be way nore of a pain than its worth ... look into the curses module

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following snippet in a separate thread/process:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys
import datetime

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), end="\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.4)
```